# Run 'HTTP-POST' method on application RUN (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: intellij-idea, http-post

I am looking for a solution when I run my program it would execute an `HTTP-POST` method. But it looks like there are no HTTP-REQUEST option in intelliJ build configurations. So I have thought of a way having a batch script execute a java application that would do that but that seems just over-complicating things. Any suggestions?

Research:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-build-configurations.html

Nothing found that would help me do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a simple Java application using the Apache http libary which sends a POST request. Here is the [apache documentation](http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/).